# Get content based on CSS pseudo class

Tags: javascript

I have a CSS declaration as follows:

```
span.boshbashbosh:nth-child(1):active:after {
  content: 'FC';
}
```

I am trying to access the content (**FC**) it by using:

```
var content = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName("boshbashbosh:nth")[0], '::active').getPropertyValue('content');
alert(content);
```

However, all the alert does is show `normal` or `none`

Any advice on how to do this in plain JS? If I had 1000 of these, I wouldn't want to click/hover each one, is there a way I could dump some code into the developer console to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here, the main one being that the CSS selector will only return an active element during a click interaction by the user, seeing that a click interaction causes the target element to become `:active`.

With that in mind, you could wrap your login in a `mousedown` element as shown below to extract the expected `content` value while the corresponding `span` element is `:active` as shown:

```js
document.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {

  /* When mouse down occours, look for the element that we want to read
  pseudo content from */
  var element = document.querySelector(".boshbashbosh:nth-child(1):active");

  if (element) {

    /* If the target element is active, read the content of the ::after
    pseudo element */
    var content = window.getComputedStyle(element, ":after")
      .getPropertyValue("content");

    alert(content);
  }
})
```

```css
span.boshbashbosh:nth-child(1):active:after {
  content: 'FC';
}


/* Added for clarity/usability of snippet */
span {
  background: pink;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  height: 1rem;
}

span.boshbashbosh:active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>Clicking first box alerts the ::after content</p>
<div>
  <span class="boshbashbosh"></span>
  <span class="boshbashbosh"></span>
  <span class="boshbashbosh"></span>
</div>
```

I've also replaced the `getElementsByClassName()` call with [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to simplify the code. Hope that helps!

#### Update

To access the content of multiple pseduo elements, you could adapt the snippet above as follows:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".boshbashbosh").forEach((element) => {

    var content = window.getComputedStyle(element, ":after")
      .getPropertyValue("content");
      
    console.log(content);
});
```

```css
span.boshbashbosh:nth-child(1):after {
  content: 'FC';
}
span.boshbashbosh:nth-child(2):after {
  content: 'EB';
}
span.boshbashbosh:nth-child(3):after {
  content: 'DA';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="boshbashbosh"></span>
  <span class="boshbashbosh"></span>
  <span class="boshbashbosh"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great - I'll add this to the question - but I need to run the script in the developer console and for it to prompt/log. If had for example 1000 of them, I wouldn't want to do each one manually

Comment: You're welcome - so you have thousands of `boshbashbosh` span elements and you want to log their pseduo `content` to console?

Comment: Yeah - pretty much that is it - console.log() to start with but at some point I'd want to build a string and display to the user but for testing, console.log will suffice

Comment: Is the pseudo content only present when the element is `:active`?  or can `:active` be removed? I don't believe there's a way to invoke `:active` with javascript directly

Comment: Active can't be removed since it's not generated by me and I have no control over it :-(